# Container width to fit iframe width

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i resize my container to fit the iFrame width. I have placed an iframe with a width of 100% in the body. If the width of the iframe is greater than my container width, it displays a scroll bar within the iframe instead of the whole page. How do i resize my container to fit the width of iFrame's content (iFrame content is another website).

Comment: If you do not have control over the other website then it is difficult to automatically adjust the value since the other website inside the iframe will shrink to fit the space provided.

Comment: If your iframe is 100% already, I don't think you can have a bigger container without scrollbars. If you hate scrollbars, consider `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Officially it's hardly supported yet but the `seamless` attribute has a nice effect on many browsers. Better than the inline `scrollbar="no"` hack.

Comment: @Huey That's why i am asking if there is any way to get the width of the iframe contents, so i can dynamically resize my container width. If such thing is not possible, i want scroll bar to display for the web page itself instead of the iframe. The user must go to the bottom of the iframe to scroll horizontally, but it would be easier if scroll bar appeared fixed, i.e as a page scroll

Comment: `$("iframe").width()`?